# Support for SAX 2.0 compilant parser

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a code which uses JAXB with SAX to unmarshal an xml source to java object. Later I read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html) document and came to know that if I dont provide a SAX parser, the JAXB provider will choose a default parser. What does default parser means? If I do not provide a SAX 2.0 parser will it parse the document using DOM or any other technique? Or will it use a SAX parser which is less than 2.0 version.

We are using the javax.xml.bind jaxb-api. How can I know which SAX parser it uses. If I have to definitely use a SAX2.0 compilant parser with JAXB then, what the different parsers available. What is all this confusion? I totally messed. Atleast I want to read a good document which explains about parsing techniques, which parser to use and different kinds of parsers and different kind of JAXB providers etc.

Till now I only know that JAXB is a specification. Standard java distributed by Oracle gives a default implementation of the specification. Besides there are other implementations like Metro, Eclipselink MOXy, apache camel's JAXB implementation. Just now I came to know that there are different parser versions used in parsing techniques if I understood properly.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the  [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

> Later I read this document and came to know that if I dont provide a
>   SAX parser, the JAXB provider will choose a default parser. What does
>   default parser means?

When you ask a [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation to unmarshal something like an `InputStream` the JAXB implementation is free to parse the XML as it sees fit (i.e. SAX, StAX, or some proprietary parser).

If you want to force your JAXB implementation to use a specfic SAX parser then you could do one of the following:

**Option #1 - UnmarshallerHandler**

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler = unmarshaller.getUnmarshallerHandler();

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        xr.setContentHandler(unmarshallerHandler);
        xr.parse("input.xml");

        Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshallerHandler.getResult();
    }

}
```

**Option #2 - SAXSource**

You can create an instance of `SAXSource` on an `XMLReader` and have JAXB unmarshal from that.  JAXB will use the `XMLReader` passed in.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource;
import org.xml.sax.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        InputSource xml = new InputSource("input.xml");

        SAXSource saxSource = new SAXSource(xr, xml);
        Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(saxSource);
    }

}
```

---

> Till now I only know that JAXB is a specification. Standard java
>   distributed by Oracle gives a default implementation of the
>   specification. Besides there are other implementations like Metro,
>   Eclipselink MOXy, apache camel's JAXB implementation. Just now I came
>   to know that there are different parser versions used in parsing
>   techniques if I understood properly.

Ultimately it is not important to know which underlying parser is used by a JAXB implementation (it can even change between versions).  A JAXB implementation is required to pass the TCK and will continue to work in a consistent way.  If you want it to use a specific SAX parser use one of the approaches mentioned above.  If you want it to use StAX pass it an instance of `XMLStreamReader` to unmarshal, and if you want it to use DOM pass it an instance of `Document` to unmarshal.

Comment: Now I am using option #2. This part "Unmarshalling from a javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource using a client specified validating SAX2.0 parser" in the document http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html confused me. I did not understand what this is.